# Cannot connect with FreeNX to Ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have recently spun up a new Ubuntu 12.04 instance in AWS. I had no issues connecting to and opening an SSH terminal to the server. Having connected to the instance, I was able to install the Ubuntu desktop and FreeNX without any problem, as well as enabling password authentication on the server instance.

I downloaded and installed the NX Client for Windows on a PC running Windows 8. After entering the user credentials I can connect to and authenticate into the server. I'm brand new to the Linux world, but at this point everything was going so smoothly I was about ready to throw my Windows licenses to the dogs - good thing I held off on that.

**"Problem: At the client, the !M logo window appears, but after a few seconds that window just closes, even without showing any error message."**

That problem statement is in quotes because it's precisely the issue described in FreeNX Ubuntu Community support documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX#Troubleshooting.

So naturally I follow the solution in the guide:

**"Solution: The issue is due custom VNC configuration. In the server, access your home directory and run these commands,"**

```
sudo rm .Xauthority*
touch .Xauthority
chmod 600 .Xauthority
```

Unfortunately, this did absolutely nothing to resolve the issue. The problem would be easier to diagnose if I had an error message, but reference the Problem statement, there is no error message to be had. Several hours of googling yielded nothing, so wondering if anyone here has encountered this problem in the past, and if so, they would be willing to help.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like a FreeNX/Ubuntu problem than an EC2 problem. You may find someone here who knows the answer, but I would consider asking at http://askubuntu.com or http://ubuntuforums.org.